# Condensing a switch statement?

Tags: c++, switch-statement

Something I've wondered for awhile as it seems to crop up in my in-experienced code quite a bit.

I have some code that uses a switch statement a lot, but all its really doing is accessing a different queue each time.

```
void store(int toSwitchOn, float posx, float posy){ 
    myDataStruct newValue;
    newValue.psX = posx;
    newValue.psY = posy;

    switch(toSwitchOn){
        case 1:
            queue1.push(newValue);          
            break;
        case 2:
            queue2.push(newValue);          
            break;
        case 3:
            queue3.push(newValue);
            break;
        case 4:
            queue4.push(newValue);
            break;
        case 5:
            queue5.push(newValue);
            break;
    }


}
```

The only thing that changes in each statement is the queue variable. Is there some ingenious way to condense this sort of repetitive code?

Comment: Use an array of queues?

Comment: From the looks of it, you have global queues. You should be passing them into the function instead. This is easy with a vector; have a parameter of type `std::vector<std::queue<someType> > &`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Store your queues in a vector.

```
std::vector<std::queue<someType> > queues (5);
//fill vector with your 5 queues

//this replaces the switch:
if (toSwitchOn >= 1 && toSwitchOn <= 5)
    queue [toSwitchOn - 1].push (newValue);
else
    //default switch case
```

Comment: The original code does nothing if `toSwitchOn` isn't between 1 and 5. Your code misbehaves badly.

Comment: @EricBanderhide, Whatever you do between creating the vector and the switch statement. This includes filling the vector with queues and the data structure thing.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. A follow up question here, <someType> is that referring to what the queue will hold? Because it will be holding queues itself. Is that possible?

Comment: @EricBanderhide, that is correct, and yes, it is very possible. If you are using queues as just plain arrays without focussing on the FIFO aspects, you will want to use a vector instead. The two are *very* similar, but vectors are more suited for general use.

Answer (score 0):

```
std::vector<std::queue<someType> > queues (5); 
//toSwitchOn is of type size_t and zero indexed.
... 
if (toSwitchOn < queues.size())
   queue [toSwitchOn].push (newValue);  //0 - 1 = undefined land...     
else     //default switch case
```

Comment: If you're referencing my answer, I'm just accounting for `toSwitchOn` being in the range [1,5], which is what the switch handles.

Answer (score 0):

The obvious answers are to replace the `switch` with a `vector` or `map` lookup of the thing to switch on.

However, I see coupling between the integer and the vector index as a leaky interface.

I want to know how the caller of this function knows which integer value to use. Who told them what to use? Could they have just been given a reference to a `Storage` object instead?

Replace:

```
int function_telling_which_index_to_use_for_storage();
```

With:

```
Storage* storage_to_use();
```

Then you can say:

```
Storage* storage = storage_to_use();
// ...
storage->store(posx, posy);
```

Remember: encapsulate, encapsulate, encapsulate.